# How to pass a message from HttpResponseRedirect in Django?

Tags: django

I have a view which does the certain task and return to another view which render hello.html template.

```
def 1stview(request):
   #Do this
   #Do that
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

def success(request):
    return render_to_response('overview.html', {'overview_files': b, 'total_files':total_files, 'total_size':total_size, 'username': username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

After successfully completing 1st view I want to pass 'Successful' message in `overview.html`. There are lots of redirect to `success` view. I want to transfer message only when going through 1st view. How can I do that?

Comment: You can add GET parameter to redirect, like so `return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/?status=successful')`. And in success function, you can get that parameter: `request.GET.get('status', None)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/) to send messages between page requests.

Answer (score 44):

*Adding a more elaborative answer.*

1: Configure a message storage in your **settings.py**:

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'
```

or if you are not using sessions, use CookieStorage:

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.CookieStorage'
```

2: In your view, import **django.contrib.messages**:

```
from django.contrib import messages
```

3: Set the message data before returning the HttpResonse:

```
messages.success(request, 'Changes successfully saved.')
```

which is a shorthand for:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Changes successfully saved.')
```

The message tags (*messages.SUCCESS* in this case) can then be used in your template to i.e. add a corresponding CSS-class or hide debug-messages. Django includes a few by default but if you wish to use this with Bootstrap's default alert classes you will need to add some custom [message tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/#message-tags) for the missing ones.

4: In your template you can then use the messages like this if you are using Bootstrap alerts:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert {% if message.tags %}alert-{{ message.tags }}{% endif %}" role="alert">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

For example, Django uses 'error' as the default tag for ERROR while Bootstrap uses danger to indicate errors. The best solution is to use custom tags, but you can also monkeypatch it in your template (ugly solution):

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert {% if message.tags %}alert-{% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}danger{% else %}{{ message.tags }}{% endif %}{% endif %}" role="alert">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Be careful when using i18n** urls! If you use a link like `/whatever/` but use internationalization, it will redirect to `/en/whatever/`, thus losing the message in the request. If you use internationalization, always pass the language to the URL:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.utils.translation import get_language

messages.success(request, _('Thank you'))
return redirect('/%s/whatever/' % get_language())
```

Cost me a couple hours to understand this...

Answer (score 5):

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.success(request, _('Thank you'))
return redirect('/whatever/')
```

Answer (score 0):

After viewing this problem, there is a problem: if the redirect came from a function other than 1stview, the messages would always be displayed; thus, we must check if the redirect came from 1stview via send. GET is the current status.

```
from django.contrib import messages
def 1stview(request):
   
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/'+'?Status='+'True')

def success(request):
    Pass_1stview = request.GET.get('Status')
    if Pass_1stview :
       messages.success(request, _('Content of the messages'))
    return render_to_response('overview.html', {'overview_files': b, 'total_files':total_files, 'total_size':total_size, 'username': username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```