# How to redirect after a warning message in Django

Tags: django

I am creating a newsletter app and having issues with the redirect function working after a success message is displayed to the user.

I have already tried various approaches to refactoring -

[[How to pass a message from HttpResponseRedirect in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999134/how-to-pass-a-message-from-httpresponseredirect-in-django])

[https://github.com/zsiciarz/django-envelope/issues/28]

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse

from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template


""" Create views """
from .forms import CustomerSubscriptionForm
from .models import CustomerSubscriptionUser

def customer_subscribe(request):
    form = CustomerSubscriptionForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if CustomerSubscriptionUser.objects.filter(email=instance.email).exists():
            messages.warning(request, "So you've already subscribe to us, so visit your email to see what we have in store for you!")
            return redirect('/experiment/subscribe') - **This is where the problem is**

        else:
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, "We are excited that you're interested in being in our local dance community! We sent some more information to your email")

            subject = "Thank you for joining our community"
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = [instance.email]
            subscription_message = "Hi, LET'S DANCE. If you want to unsubscribe got to http://127.0.0.1:8000/experiment/unsubscribe/ "
            send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=to_email, message=subscription_message, fail_silently=False)    

    context = {'form': form}
    template = "experiment/subscribe.html"


    return render(request, template, context)
```

Expected result - user is redirected to the form view after submitting requested information

Actual result - Only the message.warning value is shown

Comment: You do not redirect after `messages.success` call.

Comment: @Selcuk Ok. What is the correct approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You have a `return redirect` after the failure case, but not after success. You should add the same redirect at the end of `else` clause, shouldn't you?

Comment: @Selcuk I am not sure. What I want is to take the person back to the form if the entered an email that was already submitted.